# Downgrading from OS X 10.9.2 to 10.9

Tags: macos, downgrade

The 10.9.2 upgrade completely messed up the OpenGL driver and is causing some games / graphics driven application programmed in OpenGL to have a lot of issues with particle drawing. This is unbearable and it is causing me to lose work hours. This issue did not occur in 10.9.1 and I have researched a bit and found this to be an issue in 10.9.2. I would like to rollback to 10.9.1 or 10.9 but my recovery will only install 10.9.2 and redownloading Mavericks from the App Store also installs 10.9.2. Is there a way to roll back to one of these more stable versions?

My main issue is my inability to get a copy of 10.9.1 or 10.9. I am not sure where to get any of these!

Answer (score 1):

Yah, that's the problem with O/S X there IS no way to roll back O/S upgrades. On Windows you can do it but not on O/S X.

I have said it before but it bears repeating: clone your HD before an O/S upgrade so if it goes bad you can revert from your clone.

Yeah, I know, not what you wanted or needed, but I am not aware of Apple offering old O/S versions for download (though some clever web surfer might have found such). You may have to resort to (ahem...) "alternate" means of downloading earlier versions.

I would go that route, but clone your drive first (and TEST the clone: boot from it!), make a bootable installer thumb drive, boot from it and wipe the drive. Install the O/S clean and then use the Migration Assistant to get your personal files and Apps from the clone of your drive.

Not a lot of fun but unless someone knows a legit source (apple.com) for previous installers (unlikely) you'll have to go to that other "bay" and I don't mean "e."

Comment: Time Machine backups are a good way to manage this in the future. Restore the hard disk if you have a problem.

Comment: Normally the Recovery HD should stay at 10.9 and should not include updates to 10.9.2 so you can try to restore from the Recovery HD.